# is there off-the-shelf convenient way to filter by a group column in XtraGrid GridView?

Tags: gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I know I can invoke filter editor and so on. But this is not a convenient thing, especially for non technical users. Can GridView continually display a nice filter field for a group column as it does for normal columns?

I know I can roll my own via filtering on a hidden column and so on, but that's a lot of work. Maybe there is a built-in way to do this instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the GridView.OptionsView.ShowGroupedColumns property to true, the group column will be also shown in the column header panel among other columns and thus the end-user will be able to filter by its values.